# Mathematics C level: interrest rates percentages - need help!

Tags: percentages

> The number of fish in a lake declined by 30% over 13 years. What is the average yearly decline in the number of fish?

I know how to increase, but I can't seem to figure out how to calculate decline, can anyone help explain?

Comment: There is usually nothing more than a negative sign that differentiates a decrease from an increase. Give it another try and you may get it!

Comment: if it was increase by 30% in 13 years it would be: 
1+30/100 = 1.3
13√1.3 = 1.02 -1
0.02 x 100 = 2.0%

So instead i try with a negative sign: 
1-30/100 = 0.7
13√0.7 = 0.97 + 1
1.97 x 100? = defiantly wrong answer.. :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really think,$$V=U(1+r)^n$$
where $V$ is final quantity, $U$ is initial quantity (i.e., $1$ in this case), $r$ is the annual rate of change (increase or decrease) and $n$ is the no. of years in this case.

Putting $V=1-0.3=0.7$ and $n=13$, you get $r=-0.02706357116766167$.

That is, a decrease of $2.7\%$ every year.

Comment: thank you very much frederick! Finally unlocked the quiz and can move on. (i applied your info on all the questions and got them right) thank you very much.

Comment: You are welcome. I'm glad it helped. :)

Answer (score 1):

Hint...Decreasing by $30$% is equivalent to multiplying the initial total by $0.7$

So you need to find $x$ such that $$(1-\frac{x}{100})^{13}=0.7$$